# fn:length cannot be found: org.apache.taglibs.standard.functions.Functions

Tags: jstl, struts

I have included tag library in jsp as mentioned below:

```
<%@ taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
```

And I am trying to use it in this code:

```
<c:when test="${fn:length(training.trainingevents) gt 0 }">
```

But getting below error

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The class org.apache.taglibs.standard.functions.Functions specified in TLD for the function fn:length cannot be found: org.apache.taglibs.standard.functions.Functions

Comment: Using struts-taglib-1.3.8.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, about the error of jstl tag library, but I could solve the problem by using below code,

```
<c:when test="${not empty training.trainingevents}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Error has occurred due to older jar of JSTL, use JSTL 1.2 version to resolve the issue. It worked for me.